# Force a MultiLine TextBox Horizontal ScrollBar to the left

Tags: vb.net, textbox, scrollbar

I have a `MultiLine TextBox` that is updated over a period of time as an app runs, and I've managed to make it so that the `TextBox` scrolls to the bottom, ensuring that the latest entry is always shown.

However, sometimes the text is quite long and goes off of the side of the `TextBox`, so the `Horizontal ScrollBar` scrolls to the right.

How can I amend the code below so that the `ScrollBar` is always to the left, meaning that the beginning of lines is always visible? Please note that I do not wish to wrap text, as I can't have one entry on multiple lines. Thanks.

```
Private Sub UpdateCurrentProgress(ByVal Text As String)

    If Text = "" Then Exit Sub

    Dim Textbox As TextBox = Me.txtCurrentProgress

    If Textbox.Text <> "" Then Text = vbCrLf & Text

    Textbox.AppendText(Text)
    Textbox.Select(Textbox.TextLength, 0)
    Textbox.ScrollToCaret()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select the first char at the current line like this:

```
Me.TextBox1.Select(Me.TextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine(), 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, then you need to get first the last line index and then select the first char of that line.

```
Dim lineNumber = textBox1.Lines.Count()-1
textBox1.Select(textBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lineNumber), 0)
```